# A .NET/WinForms chart control with drill-down support?

Tags: .net, winforms, charts

There's easily a few dozen chart controls out there, but I'd prefer not to download all of them to find one that has what I want. I'm just looking for one that can do drill-down. Something like this would be fabulous (click Pie):
http://demo.quietlyscheming.com/drillDown/app.html

Doesn't need to be quite so animated and flashy, of course. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [MS Chart Controls](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=130F7986-BF49-4FE5-9CA8-910AE6EA442C&displaylang=en) are pretty good and free, but I also like [Infragistics](http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/aspnet/webchart.aspx#Overview) even though they are a bit more spendy.

Comment: I'll try the MS stuff but I'm getting awfully tired of integrating redist after redist :(